# xcode in-app purchase separate restore button for approval

Tags: xcode, in-app-purchase, restore

I know apple requires a restore button for in app purchases but does it have to be directly in the UIView or can it be in an alert view along with the Buy it button? I'm trying to only have a single button in the view for both. I have a pic but aren't allowed to post them yet. I looked at apples documentation but wasn't sure.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My app was accepted by apple with the restore purchases button in an alert view with the buy it button. So it looks like the restore button isn't required to be separate in the UIView.